# custom controls and

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

hey there,
i have written a custom control for my App so things get a little bit easier for me,and so far it worked great , now i wanted to bind some data to the wrapped content but Output says that i have a binding error and my "Items" property is searched at "CLIENT.UI.SinglePageControl" instead of "CLIENT.MainPage"....

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="CLIENT.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:CLIENT.UI"

mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<Grid>
   <ui:SinglePageControl HeaderTitle="Connections">
        <ui:SinglePageControl.PageContent>

            <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="Blue" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="UI/PICS/list_connection.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </ui:SinglePageControl.PageContent>
    </ui:SinglePageControl>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your control an x:Name value and then in your binding statement include ElementName=<x:Name>

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Name="pa"
    x:Class="CLIENT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:CLIENT.UI"  
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignWidth="480" 
    d:DesignHeight="768" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" 
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" 
    Orientation="Portrait" shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"> 
    <Grid>
        <ui:SinglePageControl HeaderTitle="Connections">
             <ui:SinglePageControl.PageContent>
                 <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=pa}" Background="Blue" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                 
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="UI/PICS/list_connection.png"/> <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText, ElementName=pa}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                             </StackPanel>                     </DataTemplate>
                     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListBox>
              </ui:SinglePageControl.PageContent>
        </ui:SinglePageControl>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you're setting data contexts, etc it's difficult to tell, but judging by the details you've given, at the level of your `ListBox` your data context is the `SinglePageControl.PageContent`. Ordinarily, the data context of the parent (the `MainPage`) would be inherited down the visual tree, so the fact that it's not in this case implies that `SinglePageControl.PageContent` is setting it's own data context. If you don't need it it, then simply remove the code (`this.DataContext = this;` for example) that is setting it and the data context will then be inherited.

If you have good reason for setting a data context at the page content (which would seem perfectly reasonable), then you will need to provide a way of passing that information down, but we'll need to know a bit more about what data comes from where in order to give a good solution.